SQL Server - Error with Database Mail when recipient email has non-ASCII characters
I'm getting an error when trying to send an e-mail through DbMail, apparently because the recipient has an accent on the e-mail.
Is there anything inside SQL Server that can fix this (or that a DBA can do)?
This is the error message I'm getting through 'sysmail_event_log'
The mail could not be sent to the recipients because of the mail server failure.
(Sending Mail using Account 1 (2024-11-01T18:41:43). Exception Message: 1)
Exception Information =================== 
Exception Type: Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlIMail.MailFramework.Exceptions.BaseMailFrameworkException
Message: Cannot send mails to mail server. 
(The client or server is only configured for E-mail addresses with ASCII local-parts: someMailNáme@gmail.com)

I tried checking the database mail settings but there is nothing more than just the basic settings there, like the address, server and login info.
Edit:
Checked with the team in charge of e-mail in the company and there was nothing they could change from our side.
Also found this StackOverflow post with a similar issue that basicallly answer my question, SendGrid has no support for non-ASCII characters in the local-part of the email. This issue was open in 2018 and to this day there is still no fix for this case.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48270879/send-internationalized-email

Because it says "the client or server ...", perhaps the mail server that SQL is handing it off to is the layer that doesn't accept the non-ASCII. Can you check with the admin of that mail server?
